# Tools for Domain Specific Language/Functions

Tags: dsl

Our users can enter questions that get answered by students. Our users need a extensible, flexible way to define the correct answers to these questions (which are stored as a simple string).

I would like to expose a library of domain specific functions that users can call on to describe the correct answer. Eg:

```
exact_match("puppy") // means the correct answer is the string 'puppy'
```

or

```
contains("yesterday") // means any answer with the word 'yesterday' is correct
```

The naive implementation would involve eval'ing user supplied strings in a sandboxed runtime (like a javascript vm or ruby vm). But I'd like to go further and only allow specific functions to be called. Any other scripting would be discarded. Such that:

```
puts("foo"); contains("yesterday")
```

would be illegal. Since we don't expose or allow `puts()`.

How can I constrain the execution environment to only run a whitelist of functions? Or is there a different approach to build this kind of external-facing DSL instead of trying to constrain an existing language to a subset of functions?

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [MPS](https://www.jetbrains.com/mps/) by JetBrains if I were you, its an open source DSL creation tool. I have never used it myself, but from everything I have seen on it, it's very intuitive; and all of their other products are incredibly powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you're creating a DSL, that doesn't necessarily mean that you have to give the user the ability to enter the code in text.

The key to this is providing a list of method names and your special keyword for them, the "FunCode" tag in the code example below:

Create a mapping from keyword to code, and letting them define everything they need, and then use it.  And I would actually build my own XML parser so that it's not hackable, at least not on a list of zero-day-exploits hackable.

```
<strDefs>
  <strDef><strNam>sickStr</strNam>
          <strText>sick</strText><strNum>01</strNum><strDef>
  <strDef><strNam>pupStr</strNam>
          <strText>puppy</strText><strNum>02</strNum><strDef>
</strDefs>
<funDefs>
  <funDef><funCode>pfContainsStr</funCode><funLabel>contains</funLabel>
          <funNum>01</funNum></funDef>
  <funDef><funCode>pfXact</funCode><funLabel>exact_match</funLabel>
          <funNum>02</funNum></funDef>
</funDefs>
<queries>
 <query><fun>01</fun><str>02</str>
   </query>
</queries>
```

The above XML more represents the idea and the structure of what to do, but rather in a user interface, so the user is constrained.  The user interface code that allows the data-entry of the above data should be running on your server, and they only interact with it.  Any code that runs on their browser is hackable, because they can just save the page, edit the HTML (and/or JavaScript), and run that, which is their code now, not yours anymore.

You can't really open the door (pandora's box) and allow just anyone to write just any code and have it evaluated / interpreted by the language parser, because some hacker is going to exploit it.  You must lock down the strings, probably by having them enter them into your database in an earlier step, and each string gets its own token that YOU generate (a SQL Server primary key is very simple, usable, and secure), but give them a display representation so it's readable to them.

Then give them a list of methods / functions they can use, along with a token (a primary key can also serve here, perhaps with a kind of table prefix) and also a display representation (label).

If you have them put all of their labels into yet another table, you can have SQL make sure that all of their labels are unique to each other in the whole "language", and then you can allow them to try to define their expressions in the language they want to use.  This has the advantage that foreign languages can be used, but you don't have to do anything terribly special.

An important piece would be the verify button, that would translate their expression into unique tokens and back again, checking that the round-trip was successful.  If it wasn't successful, there's some kind of ambiguity, and you might be able to allow them an option to use the list of tokens as the source in that case.

If you heavily rely on set-based logic for the underlying foundation of the language and your tables, you should be able to produce a coherent DSL that works.  Many DSL creation problems are ones of integrity, where there are underlying assumptions that are contradictory, unintentionally mutually exclusive, or nonsensical.  Truth is an unshakeable foundation.  Anything else has a lie somewhere -- that you're trying to build on.

Sudoku is illustrative here.  When you screw up a Sudoku, you often don't know that you have done so, and you keep building on that false foundation, until you get to the completion of the puzzle, and one whole string of assumptions disagrees with a different string of assumptions.  They can't both be true.  But you can't tell where you went wrong because you're too far away from the mistake and can not work backwards (easily).  All steps taken look correct.  A DSL, a database schema, and code, are all this way.  Baby steps, that are double- and even triple-checked, and hopefully "correct by inspection", are the best way to "grow" a DSL, slowly, piece-by-piece.  The best way to not have flaws is to not add them in the first place.

You don't want bugs in your DSL. Keep it spartan.  KISS - Keep it simple, Sparticus! And I have personally found that keeping it set-based, if not overtly, under the covers, accomplishes this very well.

Finally, to be able to think this way, I've studied languages for a long time, and have cultivated a curiosity about how languages have come to be.  Books are a good quality source of information, as they have a higher quality level than the internet, which is nevertheless also an indispensable source.  Some of my favorite languages:  Forth, Factor, SETL, F#, C#, Visual FoxPro (especially for its embedded SQL), T-SQL, Common LISP, Clojure, and probably my favorite, [Dylan, an INFIX Lisp without parentheses that Apple experimented with and abandoned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dylan_(programming_language)), with a syntax that seems to me reminiscent of Pascal, which I sort of liked.  The language list is actually much longer than that (and I haven't written code for many of them -- just studied them or their genesis), but that's enough for now.

One of my favorite books, and immensely interesting for the "people" side of it, is ["Masterminds of Programming: Conversations with the Creators of Major Programming Languages"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0043D2EEU) (Theory in Practice (O'Reilly)) 1st Edition, Kindle Edition
by Federico Biancuzzi (Author), Chromatic (Author)

By the way, don't let them compromise the integrity of your DSL -- require that it is expressible set-based, and things should go well (IMHO). I hope it works out well for you. Add a comment to my answer telling me how it worked out, if you think of it. And don't forget to choose my answer if you think it's the best!  We work hard for the money! ;-)